# Ruby Hash.merge with specified keys only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm pretty sure I saw on a Rails related site something along the lines of:

```
def my_function(*opts)
  opts.require_keys(:first, :second, :third)
end
```

And if one of the keys in `require_keys` weren't specified, or if there were keys that weren't specified, an exception was raised. I've been looking through ActiveSupport and I guess I might be looking for something like the inverse of [except](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Except.html#M000249).

I like to try and use as much of the framework as possible compared to writing my own code, that's the reason I'm asking when I know how to make the same functionality on my own. :)

At the moment I'm doing it through the normal `merge` routine and making sure that I have what I need with some IFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method you're thinking of is `assert_valid_keys` ([documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/assert_valid_keys)) but this only raises an exception if any unexpected keys exist in the hash, not if any of the specified keys are missing. i.e. if a hash is being used to pass options to a method it can be used to check for invalid options not for required options.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was thinking about. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this yourself relatively easily.  As was stated in an earlier answer, half your work is done for you in `assert_valid_keys`.  You can roll your own method to do the rest.

```
def my_function( *opts )
  opts.require_and_assert_keys( :first, :second, :third )
end
```

create `lib/hash_extensions.rb` with the following:

```
class Hash
  def require_and_assert_keys( *required_keys )
    assert_valid_keys( keys )
    missing_keys = required_keys.inject(missing=[]) do |missing, key|
      has_key?( key ) ? missing : missing.push( key )
    end
    raise( ArgumentError, "Missing key(s): #{missing_keys.join( ", ")}" ) unless missing_keys.empty?
  end
end
```

finally, in `config/environment.rb`, add this to make it work:

```
require 'hash_extensions'
```